# Primus failed to load libraries in Raring

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, bumblebee

Bumblebee is working fine. But primus is giving me an issue.

```
vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxspheres
primus: fatal: failed to load any of the libraries: /usr/lib/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1:/usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1
libnvidia-tls.so.304.88: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib32/nvidia-304/libGL.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I've changed the bridge mode in bumblebee.conf to primus to no avail

ls -la /usr/lib/nvidia*

```
/usr/lib/nvidia:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 24 10:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 176 root root 24576 Apr 26 03:50 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   120 Jun 29  2012 pre-install

/usr/lib/nvidia-304:
total 84392
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root     4096 Apr 25 16:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 176 root root    24576 Apr 26 03:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        0 Apr 10 09:21 alt_ld.so.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr 25 16:32 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       42 Apr 10 09:22 ld.so.conf
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       17 Apr 10 09:21 libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       17 Apr 10 09:21 libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 10219344 Apr 10 09:22 libcuda.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       10 Apr 10 09:21 libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       15 Apr 10 09:21 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1076560 Apr 10 09:22 libGL.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       15 Apr 10 09:21 libnvcuvid.so -> libnvcuvid.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       20 Apr 10 09:21 libnvcuvid.so.1 ->  libnvcuvid.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2196224 Apr 10 09:22 libnvcuvid.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-cfg.so -> libnvidia-cfg.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-cfg.so.1 -> libnvidia-cfg.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   144864 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-cfg.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-compiler.so -> libnvidia-compiler.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       28 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-compiler.so.1 -> libnvidia-compiler.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 27730224 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-compiler.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 35454032 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-glcore.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       17 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-ml.so -> libnvidia-ml.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       22 Apr 10 09:21 libnvidia-ml.so.1 -> libnvidia-ml.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   394280 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-ml.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       26 Apr 25 16:33 libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -> libnvidia-opencl.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8628320 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-opencl.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    11704 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-tls.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 25 16:33 libnvidia-wfb.so.1 -> libnvidia-wfb.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   295272 Apr 10 09:22 libnvidia-wfb.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       14 Apr 10 09:21 libOpenCL.so -> libOpenCL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 Apr 10 09:21 libOpenCL.so.1 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Apr 10 09:21 libOpenCL.so.1.0 -> libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    21296 Apr 10 09:22 libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 10 09:21 libXvMCNVIDIA_dynamic.so.1 -> libXvMCNVIDIA.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 10 09:21 libXvMCNVIDIA.so -> libXvMCNVIDIA.so.304.88
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Apr 10 09:21 libXvMCNVIDIA.so.1 -> libXvMCNVIDIA.so.304.88
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   167000 Apr 10 09:22 libXvMCNVIDIA.so.304.88
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr 25 16:32 tls
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr 25 16:32 vdpau
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     4096 Apr 25 16:32 xorg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root       27 Apr 10 09:22 XvMCConfig

/usr/lib/nvidia-settings-304:
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 176 root root 24576 Apr 26 03:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:32 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:32 include
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    29 Apr 10 09:20 ld.so.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 23062 Apr 10 09:20 libXNVCtrl.a
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:32 share
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:32 usr
```

Comment: how do you install primus ?

Comment: through apt-get just as I did with quantal and mint 14

Comment: have you added primus ppa then install or withh bumblebee ppa ?

Comment: I used the bumblebee ppa

Comment: vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus firefox  <<< assuming that you have firefox installed ... check this command and update

Comment: vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus firefox 

(process:3056): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
^C[ 1154.903833] [WARN]Received Interrupt signal.

Comment: its firefox error dont worry about it .. vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus glxspheres

Comment: I assumed as much. That command seems to work. Results in ~270 fps where optirun alone results in a laughable ~62

Comment: its mean all things working fine , and the firefox error ignore it

Comment: I seem to get similar results running optirun with vblank_mode=0

Comment: well with optirun glxspheres i am having 119.763802 frames/sec - 116.459279 Mpixels/sec and with vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus glxspheres 232.861565 frames/sec - 244.446537 Mpixels/sec

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /usr/lib/nvidia*` (use some paste service like paste.ubuntu.com)?

Comment: It's far too long to list here as a comment, I've added it to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a chat with Amonakov (one of the developpers of primus) about this yesterday in IRC. He told me that this is a problem that occurs presently in the primus version available in the Ubuntu PPA. As Mr Double Xxx suggested, the remedy is to use `optirun -b primus` instead. It is a different command than `primusrun`, but it does the same. The `-b` option stands for the *bridge* you use.

To use `vblank_mode=0` for benchmarking purposes, just run

```
vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus
```

This will most likely be updated very soon.

#### Update:

In the latest version of primus for Ubuntu, the command `primusrun` is again fully functional.

Comment: Awesome. He should post this as a notice in launchpad.

Comment: I am at work now with no access to IRC so I can't tell him. For what I know the `primusrun` command is **not** going to be deprecated.

Comment: That is very good to know.

Answer (score 0):

[To use the new Primus backend](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/bumblebee-31-released-with-primus.html), you'll also have to install Primus:

```
 sudo apt-get install primus
```

64bit: you also need to install "primus-libs-ia32:i386" (note that if you're using the Primus PPA, the package you need to install is "primus-lib:i386"):

```
 sudo apt-get install primus-libs-ia32:i386
```

You need to run primus with the following command

```
 vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus glxspheres
```

and ignore firefox error if you running firefox...

If bridge is auto  you can view the difference

```
 x@Ubuntu:~$ optirun glxspheres 
 Polygons in scene: 62464
 Visual ID of window: 0x20
 Context is Direct
 OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2
 95.059492 frames/sec - 106.086393 Mpixels/sec
 106.950557 frames/sec - 110.888809 Mpixels/sec
 119.763802 frames/sec - 116.459279 Mpixels/sec

 x@Ubuntu:~$ vblank_mode=0 optirun -b primus glxspheres
 ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
 ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
 Polygons in scene: 62464
 ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
 ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
 Visual ID of window: 0x20
 Context is Direct
 OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2
 225.607877 frames/sec - 251.778391 Mpixels/sec
 232.861565 frames/sec - 244.446537 Mpixels/sec
```

Comment: Has the primusrun command been deprecated?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/bumblebee-31-released-with-primus.html  << read about primus ... i dont know about primusrun ..but its the only way i found without error

Comment: also please check my config in my answer as well and read comments as well http://askubuntu.com/questions/285647/bumblebee-issue-with-13-04/285649#285649

Comment: Very well, I'll check in a few hours and get back to you. Its getting a tad too late and I'm in need of some rest.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am definitely enjoying this awesomely helpful community Ubuntu has garnered over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Problems have been solved with the latest versions of primus and bumblebee.