# Problem with nvidia/bumblebee

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I recently had to reinstall my Ubuntu 14.04.3 and now have problems with using bumblebee. I installed it as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee, but when I try to check it I get this:

```
ilya@ilya-GE40-2OL:~$ primusrun glxgears
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please
```

Or

```
ilya@ilya-GE40-2OL:~$ optirun glxgears
[  121.851700] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please

[  121.851723] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Any ideas?

PS
My laptop is MSI GE40 2OL with nvidia card G750M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the old driver and bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
```

Now add this PPA and install the driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Now reinstall bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Now just reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

This will ensure you have the latest driver and bumblebee installed.

Comment: Can it be changed without restarting X server? As far as I know nvidia-prime requires that, and I really don't want to do it every time I need to run a programme with nvidia graphics...

Comment: I don't have a laptop on me to check but I am sure you can set it to always use just Nvidia if you wish. Perhaps just wait and see if someone using it right now can comment or just give it a go, if you don't like it uninstall it like this `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

Comment: I also don't want to have it use Nvidia all the time, the lifetime would be horrible then.

Comment: Looking at some old questions about bumblebee an updated driver should fix this error, I will update the answer with modern instructions based on http://askubuntu.com/questions/295270/failing-to-initialize-nvidia-gpu